# Passar value de um button para uma variavel php atraves de POST utilzando AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, post

Olá gostaria de pedir uma ajudar, começei a utilizar ajax recentemente e estou tendo um problema que não consegui identificar com meu pouco conhecimento. Estou desenvolvendo um projeto que quero pegar o value de um button assim que ele for pressionado e retornar esse valor para a mesma pagina em uma variavel $_POST utilizando AJAX. Ai que começa o problema, eu consegui desenvolver o script mas na hora de retornar este valor ele não envia para $_POST, ele chega a ser mostrado na parte de "Network" do browser e também no console.log() mas quando tento dar um var_dump no php o valor sempre é empty. Segua uma imagem do que está acontecendo:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo o código: painel.php

```
    <div class="col bg-light ">
        <div class="shadow-lg p-4">
            <?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
            <?php
            while ($resultcatglist = $categolist ->fetch_array()){
            ?>
              <button  type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btnenviar" value="<?php echo 
                $resultcatglist["id"] ?>">
                <?php echo $resultcatglist["nome"];?>
              </button>
         <?php } ?>
 </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$( ".btnenviar" ).click(function() {
  var btnvalue = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  dataType:"html",
  url: "painel.php",
  data:{"valor":btnvalue}
})
  .done(function( data ) {
    console.log( "Data Saved: " + btnvalue );
  });
});
```

Comment: Experimenta da um console.log($(this)) e ver se ele está pegando o elemento correto.

Comment: Está, retornou certinho eu acredito.

Comment: Minha sugestão é separar o script para essa requisição ajax (ex. processa Ajax.php do script. painel.php. Nesse processaAjax você insere a sua lógica e retorna uma resposta em json. Na configs da chamada ajax, o dataType deixa como json ( que se refere ao tipo de resposta esperado). Nesse post do SO em inglês tem um exemplo que pode te ajudar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php
Estou no celular e é complicado escrever um exemplo

Comment: Tentei fazer desta maneira e mesmo assim não foi, é como se não tivesse sendo enviado. Tentei ler a documentação do Jquery mas confesso que ainda estou perdido acredito que falta algo. Obs: quando dou um console.log(data) ele retorna toda minha pagina html... e quando eu seto esse data em alguma div meu $_POST recebe o valor.